# LongListSelector ListHeaderTemplate

Tags: list, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I have a LongListSelector in my WP8 app with an ItemTemplate and a HeaderTemplate and a 
ObservableCollection list and within that list there is another list.

ViewModel:

```
Public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.FeedItems = new ObservableCollection<FeedItem>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> FeedItems { get; private set; }
```

etc, etc,

Model:

```
public class FeedItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _index;
    private string _AuthorName;

    private ObservableCollection<FeedItemComment> _Comments;

    public int index
    {
        get { return _index; }
        set
        {
            if (_index != value)
            {
                _index = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("index");
            }
        }
    }
    public string AuthorName
    {
        get { return _AuthorName; }
        set
        {
            if (_AuthorName != value)
            {
                _AuthorName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AuthorName");
            }
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<FeedItemComment> Comments
            {
                get { return _Comments; }
        set
        {
            if (_Comments != value)
            {
                _Comments = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Comments");
            }
        }
    }
```

etc etc
The FeedItemComment is pretty much the same as above

Details view code behind, navigating to event

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataContext == null)
        {
            string selectedIndex = "";
            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("selectedItem", out         selectedIndex))
            {
                int index = int.Parse(selectedIndex);
                DataContext = App.ViewModel.FeedItems[index];
            }
        }
    }
```

XAML, Details View, note both Feeditem and Comments have AuthorName field. The below does not work. The AuthorName in the ListHeaderTemplate does not appear. This is propably because the ItemSource is set to FeedItems, there is not specific HeaderSource

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!-- "*", otherwise scrolling is not working -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,10,0">
    <phone:LongListSelector x:Name="MainLongListSelector" Margin="0,0,0,0"    ItemsSource="{Binding FeedItems}"    SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">                


<phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,0,0,40" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10,10,10,15">
                        <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                            <Grid x:Name="ItemGrid" ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthorName}" 
            Padding="2" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"                
            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeaderTemplate>


<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="0,0,0,40" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="White" CornerRadius="10" Padding="10,10,10,15">
                        <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                            <Grid x:Name="ItemCommentGrid" ShowGridLines="False">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding AuthorName}" 
            Padding="2" 
            Grid.ColumnSpan="5" 
            Grid.Column="1" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"                
            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
```

The parent list is item and the child list is comments, for 1 item there can be several comments.

On the main page I have a list of items in a LongListSelector and when clicking that I open the selected item to a details view and list the comments underneath it.

On the details page I have also a LongListSelector where I populate the comments in the itemtemplate and the selected item in the header template.

The problem is that I can't get the header template populated

When I navigate to the details page the datacontext has the 1 selected item and then as a child list the comments.

I can get it working by having only the comments as a LongListSelector and the selected item outside the LongListSelector but this is not how I want it.

Any idea how to get the data to the headertemplate. The itemtemplate works fine if I set the ItemsSource="{Binding Comments}"> but the header is missing the data.

Comments is the list of comment (child collection of items)

How do I bind the data in the TextBlocks which are inside the headertemplate ?
I have tried with several version I have found with google and in some examples but no help

I have tried with for example

Any help much appreciated

Br,
Jani

Comment: Could you post the code you have thus far?

Comment: I pasted the relevant code to the post, thanks

Comment: What data do you want in the header template? Do you want the authors name in the header?

Comment: Yes, the AuthorName from the FeedItem obserable collection. If you give me that answer getting the fields is copy / paste stuff

Comment: Sorry, clicked enter too soon. So the FeedItems is the parent observable collection and inside that there is another observable collection called Comments. So 1 item can have X number of comments. The item in the header and comments in the ItemTemplate. The AuthorName is just one field in the FeedItem there are more (there is a field with the same name in the Comments also (i.e. the author of the comment)

Comment: Did anyone have any idea how to solve this ? How to bind the header template (ListHeaderTemplate) to different observable collection than the list item template (ItemTemplate). Currently I have one observable collection (FeedItems) which have then also sub observable collections. The idea is to get in the ItemTemplate the sub observable collection and in the HeaderTemplate the main observable collection.